# PowerBI - Automatic Refresh OneDrive Business From Excel File

Tags: powerbi

I have an excel sheet stored in a OneDrive Business Folder, which is updated continuously (approximately every minute). I am trying to show a live count of the number of entries in the table, as below, on a powerBI report:

[image]

[image]

From here I have tried two options:

1.Created a PowerBI Desktop File which shows the total count on a single card. I have then published this to PowerBI Service as a report.

2.Imported the excel file in via "Get Data->Files->OneDrive-Business" on PBI Service: 
[image]

I loaded in the data and then created a report as below:
[image]

However, when a change is made to the excel file on the onedrive, the report data does not update automatically when any change is made. Instead, the only way that it updates is via the "refresh now" option in datasets on PBI service:

[image]

Then once that is refreshed, I have to manually refresh the data in the report window also.

The connection between the report and the excel file is therefore available to allow the manual update, but for some reason does not automatically update when I make a change. Are there are solutions available to get this to update automatically.

I saw this cool idea, but I can't seem to get it to work:
https://bigintsolutions.com/2019/03/29/refresh-power-bi-report-every-min-and-show-on-a-tv/

I have also read many threads, with some people having the same issue I am having:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Automatic-Refresh-not-working-when-connecting-to-SharePoint/td-p/546308
I know that there should be an update every hour for PowerBI-OneDrive connections, but I was hoping there was a way for updating live.

Goal: PowerBI Service Report to update automatically, for live data feed to a TV screen, when a change is made, say every minute.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Where are you sourcing your data? Updating each minute to an Excel file seems like something that won’t scale in the long term. This sounds like a better scenario for a real-time dataset that is in hybrid mode. Then you could build a dashboard over the data and it would automatically update as the data updates. I’ve used Power Automate to push data into a real-time dataset as well.

Treb Gatte, Power BI MVP

Comment: Hi @Treb Gatte, thanks for getting in touch. I am scanning a product label every minute or so and doing a count of the number of lines scanned in. The excel sheet will be saved after every 500 items to complete the batch. Do you have any examples of this hybrid mode perhaps? I am not familiar with it, nor am I familiar with power automate.